I need to identify a component package and, if possible, the component
I need to know haw the package and/or the component of the picture. It is between the VCC supply voltage and the voltage that goes to the rest of the circuit. Apparently it does not behave like a diode, it has a resistance of approximately 1 ohm. The mesures of the package is 3.2x4.2x3mm.


There isn't a way to identify it as there are no markings. Pull it off the board and use some smart tweezers to see what it is.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Probably molded inductor, this style for example:
https://product.tdk.com/en/system/files?file=dam/doc/product/inductor/inductor/smd/catalog/inductor_commercial_decoupling_nlcv32-pf_en.pdf
You will need to measure inductance, and preferably saturation current, to more closely identify it or a substitute.  Given that it's on VCC, it's probably a fairly low value, 1µH or thereabouts.
